# Automation Google Presentations

Tags: google-sheets, automation

[image: Button Update]
I have charts in Google Presentations linked to Google Spreadsheets data, but every time I have to click the update button. It is possible some kind of schedule so the chart can update automatically?

Answer (score 2):

At this time it's not possible. It's worth to said that on May 18, 2016 Google [announced](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2016/05/apps-dev-sheets-api.html) that the Google Slides API will be launched in the comming months.